What is the historicity of the Paschal prisoner release custom in Mark?
The gospel of Mark (and other gospels) states that there was a Roman custom of releasing a prisoner in Judaea during the feast of Passover in Mark 15 6-8:

6 Now at the festival he used to release a prisoner for them, anyone for whom they asked. 7 Now a man called Barabbas was in prison with the rebels who had committed murder during the insurrection. 8 So the crowd came and began to ask Pilate to do for them according to his custom. NRSV

There appears to be no non-New Testament source attesting to this practice.
What is the historicity of this custom? Was it a Roman practice in Judaea to release a prisoner during Passover? Where does Mark get this information from? If it's a literary device, what does it accomplish?

https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/36352/is-the-story-of-barabbas-possibly-fabricated

Have you read that Q already? Seems like a very near duplicate, the second Answer does seem to cover this

@Stevecanhelp
Thanks, that second answer is a suitable answer for this question. Up to you if the questions themselves are duplicates. I thought that this was a general question about the custom of a prisoner release rather than the specific story and character of Barabbas

Sure - given that there doesn't seem to be any contemporary evidence to address your question, it probably isn't going to get any better than the Answers on the other Q - I've closed and merged accordingly. Thanks!
